# error al momento de iniciar con el npm start en microsoft terminal

Tags: javascript, qrcode

```
const qrcode = require("qrcode-terminal");

const { Client } = require("whatsapp-web.js");

const client=new Client();

client.initialize();

client.on("qr", qr=> {
    qrcode.generate(qr,{small:true});
})

client.on("ready",()=>{
    console.log("Cliente listo");
})

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
```

estaba haciendo un bot para whastapp con las librerias de qrcode y whatsapp-webb
es urgente nesecito ayuda pls ;-;

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Por favor agrega la información del error que recibes o en caso de ser necesario, el proceso que seguiste. Estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [ask] para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes

Answer (score 0):

encontre el error solo debi cambiar la secion de

```
client.on("qr", qr=> {
qrcode.generate(qr);})
```

despues de eso me salio el codigo qr pero algo grande ya que igual lo nesecito